# Parallel Stream toArray maintains order

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I read about concurrent collectors maintaining order of input list. So if i use a Collectors to ArrayList, it can guarantee ordered collection.
Also map functions on ordered list maintain the order.
I could not find any documentation around order preservation in toArray

> Even when a pipeline is constrained to produce a result that is consistent with the encounter order of the stream source (for example, IntStream.range(0,5).parallel().map(x -> x*2).toArray() must produce [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]), no guarantees are made as to the order in which the mapper function is applied to individual elements, or in what thread any behavioral parameter is executed for a given element.

So will

```
Stream.map(x->x).toArray()
```

produce ordered results? Or should I use collectors.

Comment: Isn’t that cited part of the documentation explicit enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cited part of [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) already states by example that both, `map` and `toArray` will maintain the encounter order.

When you go through the [`Stream` API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) you’ll see that it never makes an explicit statement about operations which maintain the encounter order, but does it the other way round, it explicitly states when an operation is *unordered* or has special policies depending on the ordered state.

- obviously `unordered()` retracts the encounter order explicitly
- `forEach` and `findAny` do not respect the encounter order
- `Stream.concat` returns an unordered stream if at least one of the two input streams is unordered (a debatable behavior, but that’s how it is)
- `Stream.generate()` generates an unordered stream
- `skip`, `limit`, `takeWhile`, and `dropWhile` respect the encounter order, which may cause significant performance penalties in parallel executions
- `distinct()` and `sorted()` are stable for ordered streams, `distinct()` may have significantly better parallel performance when the stream is unordered
- `collect(Collector)` may behave as unordered if the collector is unordered, which is only hinted by the statement that the operation will be concurrent if the collector is concurrent and either the stream is unordered *or* the collector is unordered. For more details, we have to refer the [`Collector` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collector.html) and [the builtin collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

Note that while the operations `count()`, `allMatch`, `anyMatch`, and `noneMatch` have no statement about the encounter order, these operations have a semantic that implies that the result should not depend on the encounter order at all.